# Increasing inventory quantity based on SQL Server unique key violation

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012

I am working on an inventory control system and I have two tables in SQL Server.

Products:

```
    PRDCTID  | PRDCTCODE |PRDCTNAME| DATEADDED
    ---------|-----------|---------|---------
    1        |       200 |VW Milk  | 2017/05/15
    2        |       310 |AX Milk  | 2011/05/15
    3        |       255 |XY Bread | 2000/05/15
    4        |       115 |ZZ BREAD | 1999/05/15
```

Product Count:

```
     PRDCTCODE |PRDCTCOUNT| DATEUPDATED
    -----------|----------|---------
           200 |30        | 2017/05/15
           310 |10        | 2011/05/15
           255 |50        | 2000/05/15
           115 |200       | 1999/05/15
```

I will be using the `PRDCTCODE` column from the `Products` table as a foreign key on the `PRDCTCODE` column in the `Product Count` table. The `PRDCTCODE` column in the `Products` table will have a unique key constraint placed on it so that each item in my inventory can only appear once in my `Products` table and what I intend to do thereafter is show the actual quantity inside my `Product Count` table.

What I would like to know is: is it possible to increase the product's quantity in the `PRDCTCOUNT` column in the `Product Count` table based on a violation of the unique key constraint on the `PRDCTCODE` column in the `Products` table when scanning in an identical item?

For example: when scanning 20 bottles of the same milk into inventory, if the milk already exists in the `Products` table, I can use the violation error of the unique key constraint in the `PRDCTCODE` column to increase the `PRDCTCOUNT` column in the `Product Count` table?

Is that a good idea? What problem can be caused if I intentionally cause/use violations to increase my product quantity instead of iterating through the entire `Product Count` table to find the matching product first, read the quantity in the `PRDCTCOUNT` column and then increase/decrease the quantity based on scanning in or selling?

If there are only 10 000 or 50 000 rows I suppose iterating every time an item is scanned wouldn't be a problem but what if there are a 100 000 rows in the `Product Count` table and 1000 bottles of milk are being scanned in? I can imagine that having to iterate through 100 000 rows 1000 times, as fast as someone can scan the bottles of milk in might cause a problem?

Comment: Unique constraints control the addition of new _records_.  Why would you use this to control number of products added?

Comment: To avoid having to search through the table to find the item first. The violation would then create the opportunity to update the PRDCTCOUNT field without the possibility of the item not being present in the Product Count table and without having to check that it's there first. In other words, if there's a violation that means the item exists in the Product Count table so the only thing left to do is an update query.

Comment: A database is a flat object with rows and columns.  Tables are views of the database which only contain a portion of the database to make it easier to read and write.  So it is physically impossible to have the same cell in the database have two different values at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want an **upsert**, but are describing it the other way around. I recommend reading this article which offers an in-depth explanation of how to do this properly: [Sam Saffron''s upsert (update/insert) patterns](https://samsaffron.com/blog/archive/2007/04/04/14.aspx)

A rough version of what a procedure would look like for that:

```
create procedure dbo.ProductCount_upsert (
  @prdctcode int
  ) as 
begin
  set nocount, xact_abort on;
  begin tran
    update dbo.ProductCount (with serializable)
      set prdctcount = prdctcount +1
        , dateupdated = getdate()
      where prdctcode = @prdctcode;
    if @@rowcount = 0
    begin;
      insert into dbo.ProductCount (prdctcode, prdctcount, dateupdated) 
      values (@prdctcode, 1, getdate());
    end;
  commit tran
end;
```